# Computing eigenvalues with characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two questions about computing eigenvalues with the characteristic polynomial.

1. Eigenvalues exist if and only if I can factor the polynomial?? For example, I know i can calculate the roots of $ t^2 - 3t + 3 $ but I would use a quadratic formula for that.
2. An exercise asks me to find the eigenvalues of a matrix  $$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{array}\right)$$
   Computing $\det(A-tI) $ I get $ t^2 - 3t + 3 $.
   Computing $\det(tI -A) $ I get $ t^2 - 3t - 4 = (t-4)(t + 1) $
   I didn't come up with the last solution, but I'm not even sure why it is correct to compute $\det(tI -A) $ instead of $\det(A-tI) $, and in which cases it is more convenient to do that.

Comment: You made an error in computing $\det(A-tI)$.  Check your arithmetic.

Comment: Oh, right. The polynomials are equal now

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same because the both determinants will be the same polynomial except possibly off by a negative sign. And this doesnt affect the roots of the polynomials. Either way is equally easy/hard.

Comment: I don't think that it's easier to do the standard way as it leaves an annoying minus in front of the highest power that makes me feel uncomfortable

Comment: Then divide by -1. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues may be imaginary, if you calculate the characteristic polynomial and set it equal to zero to find the roots then just as with a quadratic which may have no real solutions the characteristic polynomial may have imaginary roots. Take a rotation matrix as an example [Eigenvalues of a rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325778/eigenvalues-of-a-rotation)